# Resolving blanks when calculating attributes for almost 2 million polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3

I am starting with this Hazard Parcel Exposure dataset from the Metropolitan Transportation Commission which I downloaded as a shapefile.

http://opendata.mtc.ca.gov/datasets/parcel-hazard-exposure

I am using QGIS 3.4.3-Madeira on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6.

I tried to convert boolean to numeric values but the values did not calculate all the way through. Why are there blank rows when calculating attributes in QGIS3?

At first I thought maybe there is a selection on, but I did it all again with nothing selected and the same thing happened.

The 5 boolean attributes are shown below.

[image: boolean_attributes]

My goal is to convert each to a numeric value, sum into a new field, and represent each parcel with categorized symbology like so:

[image: categorized_symbology]

Where 0 means no hazards and 5 means there are 5 hazards (all five attributes are True).

First I added temporary fields for each hazard attribute and calculated so it is becomes numerical. This is what I calculated for the first boolean attribute.

```
"infltzone"='True'
```

[image: temporary_attributes]

The result of calculating that into the field "fltzone" is that True values become 1 and False values become 0. Then I sum all the values into a new field I called hazsum using this calculation:

```
 "fltzone"  +  "lndstdy"  +  "liqstdy"  +   "lndsus"  +  "liqsus"
```

The fields calculated and it initially looked like they calculated. But I tried to symbolize it and it looked like this, with many parcels without a numerical hazard exposure value:

[image: incomplete_map]

When I identify a parcel with a hazsum, it looks great:

[image: good_id]

But when identifying a neighboring parcel with no hazsum...

[image: bad_id]

I tried to export to Excel and do the calculations there but it kept crashing.

Can you suggest a method to accomplish my goal or to explain why my calculation did not complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way! TLDR I used postgres.

[image: hazmap]

I used:
PostgreSQL 11 via https://postgresapp.com/documentation/ and
pgAdmin 4.1 via https://www.pgadmin.org,

and the query I used was:

```
ALTER TABLE hazards 
    ADD fltzone integer, 
    ADD lndstdy integer, 
    ADD liqstdy integer, 
    ADD lndsus integer, 
    ADD liqsus integer, 
    ADD hazsum integer;
UPDATE hazards SET
    fltzone = CASE WHEN in_fltzone = 'True' THEN 1 else 0 END,
    lndstdy = CASE WHEN in_lndstdy = 'True' THEN 1 else 0 END,
    liqstdy = CASE WHEN in_liqstdy = 'True' THEN 1 else 0 END,
    lndsus = CASE WHEN in_lndsus = 'True' THEN 1 else 0 END,
    liqsus = CASE WHEN in_liqsus = 'True' THEN 1 else 0 END;
```

Then seperately run:

```
UPDATE hazards SET
    hazsum = fltzone + lndstdy + liqstdy + lndsus + liqsus;
```